# Getting Not Supported Error while using Ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I strangle to be able to catch this error.
While on desktop, this code raise this  `NotSupportedError`:

[image]

I normally debug on chrome.

Here is the code:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {ScreenOrientation} from "@ionic-native/screen-orientation";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-loading',
  templateUrl: 'page-loading.html',
})
export class PageLoading {

  constructor(private screenOrientation:ScreenOrientation) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PageLoading');

    try{
        this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT).then(()=>{
          console.log('lock');
        });
    }catch(e){
      console.warn('No cordova.js')
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: ionic native or rather cordova does not work with ionic serve.. you just have to run in a device or emulator

Comment: Yes, I know, but for other plugins that is not a problem, they complain silency. I just want to silence this error on my desktop, but the try catch does not help

Comment: oh you mean in the ionic view screen?

Comment: No I use ionic serve like you said, I just don't know why I can catch these errors

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/browser.html

Comment: wonderful, I accept your answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144255/discussion-between-david-f-and-suraj).

Comment: added an example answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a class to mock ionic native classes as described in the docs [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/browser.html).

```
class ScreenOrientationMock extends ScreenOrientation {
  lock(type) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve("locked");
    })
  }
}
```

In your providers list in `ngModule` mention it should use your mocked class instead of the actual ionic native one.

```
providers: [..
    { provide: ScreenOrientation, useClass: ScreenOrientationMock }
 ]
```

This will return whatever you have set in `resolve` for screenorientation during `ionic serve`.

You can remove it once it is run in a device.

**EDIT:**

There is another possibility to suppress your error, so you will not have anything to do at the end:

```
if(this.platform.is('cordova')){
  this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
   this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT);
  })
}
```

Comment: `remove it once it is run in a device.` you mean that we have to manually change the code later to provide real classes instead of mocks when deploying the app? Or is there a way to detect the device you are running and provide the mock or not automatically?

Comment: Hi, no in fact you should not use any mock at the end. I update the response

Comment: @DavidF. thanks.. you could have added as your own answer though